# weak reference to object containing a nested strong reference, and garbage collection

Tags: java, garbage-collection, weak-references

Suppose I have a weak reference to a car which has an ordinary (strong) reference to an engine. No other references to the car or the engine exist. Can the engine be garbage collected?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes it can, that is exactly how [weak references](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_reference) are designed to work.  The weak reference is the root that your object has to the application, even though the object may have other strong references it is the *root* reference that matters and since the root reference is a weak reference the object will be a candidate for garbage collection.

For more information please see [`WeakReference`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/ref/WeakReference.html) class documentation:

> Weak reference objects, which do not
>   prevent their referents from being
>   made finalizable, finalized, and then
>   reclaimed. Weak references are most
>   often used to implement canonicalizing
>   mappings.
>
> Suppose that the garbage collector determines at a certain point in time
>   that an object is weakly reachable. At
>   that time it will atomically clear all
>   weak references to that object and all
>   weak references to any other
>   weakly-reachable objects from which
>   that object is reachable through a
>   chain of strong and soft
>   references. At the same time it
>   will declare all of the formerly
>   weakly-reachable objects to be
>   finalizable. At the same time or at
>   some later time it will enqueue those
>   newly-cleared weak references that are
>   registered with reference queues.

FYI, along with `WeakReference`, Java offers two other subclasses of [`Reference`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/ref/Reference.html): [`SoftReference`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/ref/SoftReference.html) and [`PhantomReference`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/ref/PhantomReference.html).

Comment: I've never heard the expression weak reference and it sounds like it implies some mecanism. If I understand things correctly, the question is whether engine will be garbage collected if nothing is referring car?

Comment: @James P.: WeakReference is a class in the Java standard API that indeed provides a special mechanism, namely references that do not prevent an object from being eligible for garbage collection.

Answer (score 8):

The Car instance *could* be garbage collected, but there is no guarantee that it *will* be garbage collected on the next GC cycle, or even that it will be collected at all.  For example,

- At some time before the GC runs, the application could call `get` on the `WeakReference` and save the reference to the `Car` in (for example) an attribute of some reachable object.  The `Car` instance then becomes fully reachable and no longer eligible for garbage collection.
- If the GC runs with the `Car` in the state described, the JVM spec does not guaranteed that the  weakly reachable will be detected in the next GC cycle.  For example, if a given GC cycle only collects the latest generation (and the `Car` has been promoted to an older generation) the GC won't determine that it is weakly reachable.
- Even when the GC breaks reference to the `Car` in the WeakReference, the `Car` instance is not reclaimed immediately.  Rather, the reclamation of the now unreachable `Car` will probably happen (after possible finalization) in a later GC cycle.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a unit test that demonstrates weak references. Note that System.gc() will not guarantee that the object will get garbage collected and you should not rely on it.

```
import junit.framework.TestCase;

import java.lang.ref.WeakReference;

public class WeakReferenceTest extends TestCase {


    class Car {

        Engine engine = new Engine();

    }

    class Engine {

    }

    public void testWeakReferences() {
        WeakReference<Car> carRef = new WeakReference<Car>(new Car());
        assertNotNull(carRef.get());
        System.gc();
        assertNull(carRef.get());
    }

}
```

Comment: What does the notation WeakReference<Car> mean exactly?

Comment: That call to System.gc() doesn't guarantee that the last assert will return true.

Comment: It is a parameterization of the generic class `WeakReference<T>` in which the type parameter `T` is the class `Car`.

Comment: The System.gc() will indeed not guarantee that the object will get garbage collected, and you should not rely on it.

Comment: Phil, Frederik, why not, where is it written that System.gc() might not work or what is your argument here ?

Comment: I'm currently running JUnit test and I can confirm that System.gc() does not immediately clear WeakReference.